# Setup PHP from source and mod_fgcid on CentOS 6, getting permission denied

Tags: centos, php

I have compiled PHP from source and installed it to `/opt/php/5.5.15/`

I have also installed (with `yum`) `httpd`, and `mod_fcgid`.

I am trying to configure a virtual host to exec php like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.co.nz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site.example.com/site/public
    ServerName my-site.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/my-site.example.com/logs/my-site.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/my-site.example.com/logs/my-site.example.com-access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/my-site.example.com/site/public>
        Options +indexes
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Action application/x-httpd-php /php-5.5.15-bin/php-cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    IdleTimeout 3600
    ProcessLifeTime 7200
    MaxProcessCount 64
    DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 8
    IPCConnectTimeout 300
    IPCCommTimeout 7200
    BusyTimeout 300

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    ScriptAlias /php-5.5.15-bin/ /opt/php/5.5.15/bin/

    <Directory "/opt/php">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Thu Aug 14 17:36:20 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/opt/php/5.5.15/bin/php-cgi' failed, referer: http://my-site.example.com:10080/
[Thu Aug 14 17:36:20 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: php-cgi, referer: http://my-site.example.com:10080/
```

I have tried `chmod 777 php-cgi` and `chown apache:apache php-cgi`, both made no difference.

Any ideas?

*Note: this setup works fine on Debian*

Comment: Do you run SELinux? Try setting it in permissive mode, by changing /etc/selinux/config: `SELINUX=permissive` After that, reboot the server.

Comment: Its standard CentOS 6, so presumably so (I will have to check for sure tomorrow). Is there anyway to get around it without doing this, as this is not ideal.

Comment: You can turn on auditing and see what rules are appliend, and then write your own policy which allows Apache user to run binaries from /opt/php/5.5.15/bin

That's why it's always smart to use RPM packages and not compile your own stuff. For php 5.5, you can use php55 pacakges from IUS repo: http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/
Install epel-release and ius-release manually, and then do yum install php55u-cli php55u-bcmath ... and all the other php plugins you need.

Comment: @JakovSosic looking in the current audit log it looks like httpd doesn't have exec rights (under SELinux policies) on the php-cgi bin. Any idea on how to allow it? Also the reason for this particular setup and compiling from source is that I need to run multiple version of PHP side by side.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out SELinux was denying httpd exec rights on the php-cgi bin.

Viewing the /var/log/audit/audit.log showed this.

Running the following allows it:

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /opt/php/5.5.15/bin/php-cgi
```